# In Justice League: War, how was Superman able to overcome Darkseid's brainwashing?

Tags: dc, justice-league-war, dc-animated-movie-universe

I just watched Justice League: War, but I have a question...

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War):

> Because of a brainwashing process being done on him using Darkseid's technology Superman becomes unstable and highly aggressive, resulting in him crushing Desaad to death and attacking anything in sight, including other Parademons and Batman. Batman reasons with Superman, helping him reassert his own personality

How is Superman able to get rid of the brainwashing?

Comment: There are two questions here. You might want to ask about the  "strange vests" in an additional question.

Comment: Answered your own question? "***Batman reasons with Superman, helping him reassert his own personality***"

Comment: just that? o.O , repeating himself that he is a good guy?

Comment: You're the one who watched it. What happened?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common movie trope. From [tvtropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYoureInThereSomewhereFight):

> They know that the loved one is still there somewhere. The hero will win this fight by talking the friend out of the evil influence, usually because of The Power of Friendship or The Power of Love.
>
> Often accompanied by the phrase "I know you are in there somewhere." The hero stalls the fight, trying to snap the friend out of it.

Superman, in this case, is basically freed by the unexplainable, semi-magical power of **willpower**, assisted by Batman.

Answer (score -3):

It literally isn't shown in the film, so we can't know for certain.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a really *really* poor answer. Just because it doesn't say in the film doesn't mean that there's no way of finding out what happened.

Comment: I would maybe add more detail. Just cause you didn't say much